# Cannot instantiate System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler on Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, windows, http, windows-8.1

I have a piece of code that uses System.Net.Http Library.
and when ever I create new instance of System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler an Exception occures , For Example:

```
    private async void btnTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = new System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler();
        //default constructor does the same thing :this(new HttpClientHandler())
        var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(handler);
        var resp = (await client.GetAsync("any url"));
        var content = resp.Content;
    }
```

and the Exception is :

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
'System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols' from assembly 
'System.Net.Primitives, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler..ctor()
   at MyApp.MainWindow.<btnTest_Click>d__0.MoveNext() in c:\MyApp\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 30
```

I tested the code on win 7, no exception thrown, but whatever i tried on win8.1 the same exception was thrown.

Answer (score 1):

The [System.Net.Http.HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx), [System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclienthandler(v=vs.118).aspx) and [System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage(v=vs.118).aspx) implements the IDisposable interface, and should be disposed; typically you would put them in `using` blocks.

```
using(var handler = new System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler())
{ 
    using(var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(handler))
    {
       using(var resp = (await client.GetAsync("any url")))
       {
            var content = resp.Content;
       }
    }
}
```

Anyway... I don't think this will solve your problem :P

1. I think you are using VS2015 RC, this appears to be a common issue on that version.
2. However, it is recommended for Windows 8.1 WinRT to use the [Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn298639), which works a little bit different than `System.Net.Http` one.

Using the `Windows.Web.Http` namespace:

```
using (Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter filter = new Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter())
{
     using (Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient client = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient(filter))
     {
          using (Windows.Web.Http.HttpResponseMessage resp = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("Any Uri")))
          {
               var content = resp.Content;
          }
      }
}
```

Last, you have set the `Capabilities` in the `Package.appxmanifest` to allow Internet access.

Hope this helps. Good luck!